# Parse String to get all values inside an array

Tags: javascript, regex, string, parsing

Right now i have an string that looks like.

```
const string = "<h1>Text<widget some-some-type='Some' data-some-id='ryteCAX4kaXFWmpuj'></widget><widget some-some-type='HtmlColumns' data-some-id='cw7gtkTqE49NarsS9'></widget></h1>"
```

And i would like to know how to get the text inside `data-some-id='ryteCAX4kaXFWmpuj'` aka just get `ryteCAX4kaXFWmpuj`.

**NOTE** there could be more than 100 `data-some-id` on the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMParser#DOMParser_HTML_extension_for_other_browsers) to parse the HTML string.

```js
// craete an instance of parser
var parser = new DOMParser();
const string = "<h1>Text<widget some-some-type='Some' data-some-id='ryteCAX4kaXFWmpuj'></widget><widget some-some-type='HtmlColumns' data-some-id='cw7gtkTqE49NarsS9'></widget></h1>"
  // parse the string to convert iti into dom
var doc = parser.parseFromString(string, "text/html");

// get all widget and convert NodeList to array 
// for iterating over them. You can even use Array.from()
// method in latest browsers
[].slice.call(doc.querySelectorAll('widget'))
  // iterate over them 
  .forEach(function(ele) {
    //  get data-* attribute value
    console.log(ele.dataset.someId)
  })
```

---

Or using [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) create an element with the HTML content and get the inner element.

```js
// create a div element
var div = document.createElement('div');
const string = "<h1>Text<widget some-some-type='Some' data-some-id='ryteCAX4kaXFWmpuj'></widget><widget some-some-type='HtmlColumns' data-some-id='cw7gtkTqE49NarsS9'></widget></h1>"
// set the html content of the div
div.innerHTML = string;

// get all widget and convert NodeList to array 
// for iterating over them. You can even use Array.from()
// method in latest browsers
[].slice.call(div.querySelectorAll('widget'))
  // iterate over them 
  .forEach(function(ele) {
    //  get data-* attribute value
    console.log(ele.dataset.someId)
  })
```

Comment: this just return one `data-some-id` not the 2 i need

Comment: @potatoe26 : updated

Comment: @potatoe26 then use `document.querySelectorAll` and loop over them

Comment: @PranavCBalan You can even use `Array.from()`.

Comment: @Rajesh :  compatibility issue....

Comment: works nice thank you